# How to access character inside char * using pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char, pointer-arithmetic

I've this function which print out each character inside a char * using array notation:

```
void printCharArray(char* c,int n)
{
    for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
        cout << c[i]; // or *(c+i)
}
```

So beside using notation `c[i]` or `*(c+i)`, is there any way I can achieve the same result with pointers and their arithmetic in this case?

Comment: You mean something like `c += n; while (n--) {cout << *--c;}` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 Maybe I'm a rookie but can you explain your code? It's quite difficult for me to understand. How can you use `+=` operator here and when will the `while` loop stop?

Comment: It is basically the same as accepted answer: increment pointer by `n`, test and decrement `n` in loop. and the body decrements the pointer (`--c`) then dereference it for printing. I agree that it would be more readable by splitting instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
for (char*p=c+n-1; n; n--) 
    cout << *p--;
```

By the way,  cout for char by char output is a significant overhead.  `cout.put(*p--);` would be a lighter alternative

And just in case you need to keep your arguments unchanged for futher processing, here an alternative:

```
for (char*p=c+n-1; p!=c-1; p--) 
    cout.put(*p);
```

Of course, all this assumes that n>=0.

Comment: Can you explain to me what's the returning value of `char*p=c+n-1`?

Comment: It defines a pointer p which is local to the for loop.  It's initialized to the last char of your array c (`c+n-1` is the same as `&c[n-1`]).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so `c += n` as @Jarod42 suggestion will be equal to `&c[n]`?

Comment: @ShibaTatsuiya: yes, `c += n` is `c = c + n` and `c + n == &c[n]`

Comment: Hi @Christophe this prints out from the last byte/character to the first, is there a way to print starting from the first?

Comment: @JonathanDeclanTan sure: `for(char*p=c;p!=c+n; p++) ...`